# Finding Rao-Cramer Lower bound

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

Third part of a homework problem and I understand the material, but I can't integrate this "thing"...

$f(x;\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta^2}x^{\frac{1-\theta}{\theta}}, 0<x<1, 0<\theta<\infty.$

$\ln{f(x;\theta)} = -\ln{\theta}-\ln{x}+\frac{1}{\theta}\ln{x}.$

$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial{\theta}^2}\ln{f}(x;\theta) = \frac{1}{\theta^2}-\frac{2\ln{x}}{\theta^3}.$

Now to get the Rao-Cramer lower bound we need $E[\ln{x}]$.  So

$E[\ln{x}]=\int_0^1\ln{x}\frac{1}{\theta}x^{\frac{1-\theta}{\theta}}dx.$

I don't even know where to begin......All i know is I've never seen an integral this complex before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using integration by parts we have
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \log(x)\cdot x^k\,\mathrm dx&=\lim_{a\downarrow 0}\int_a^1\log(x)\cdot x^k\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\lim_{a\downarrow 0}\left\{\log(x) \frac{1}{k+1}x^{k+1}\bigg|_a^1-\int_a^1 \frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{k+1}x^{k+1}\,\mathrm dx\right\}\\
&=\lim_{a\downarrow 0}\left\{\frac{x^k}{k+1}\log(x)\bigg|_a^1-\frac{1}{k+1}\int_a^1 x^{k}\,\mathrm dx\right\}.
\end{align}
$$
Now put $k=\frac{1-\theta}{\theta}$ and finish the calculations.

Comment: I'm chalking it up to the fact that it's 2AM and I've been at this for 6 hours.....thanks @Stefan...that was obvious now that you've shown me.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: I get $-\theta$.

Comment: I spied the solution and the author uses what I believe to be a Riemann Stieljes integral...do you know of any good text to understand Riemann Stieljes?

Comment: @ChristopherErnst: I get $-\theta^2$. Sorry, I don't know any good text on the subject of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral.